# GIT, SSH, and GIT-SHELL

Tags: ssh, git

I'm trying to set up a secure git repository server using ssh-keys and git-shell.
Since our user database is stored in a central LDAP directory, I can't change users' default shell to git-shell, so I've tried prepending the git-shell command to the public key in the authorized_users file like this:

```
command="git-shell -c $SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND" ssh-dss AAAAB3NzaC1kc3...
```

However, git-shell won't even allow me to clone the repository:

```
    dhcp202:git-ws frank$ git clone ssh://gitserver/var/repos/git/myrepo/
    Cloning into myrepo...
    fatal: What do you think I am? A shell?
    fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Any ideas appreciated...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will find a similar mechanism with [gitolite](http://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/), based on ssh and [forced command](http://oreilly.com/catalog/sshtdg/chapter/ch08.html#22858).
(including [ldap queries](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/tree/pu/contrib/ldap)).
It don't allow interactive shell however, <del>which could be your issue there</del>.

The OP [Frank Brenner](https://serverfault.com/users/75500/frank-brenner) adds:

> Ah, I figured it out - the command has to be in single quotes. I suppose `$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND` was getting expanded before git-shell was started.

That is confirmed in the gitolite forced command script is a Perl one, ending with:

```
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#       over to git now
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

if ($ENV{REQUEST_URI}) {
    log_it($ENV{REQUEST_URI});
    exec $ENV{GIT_HTTP_BACKEND};
    # the GIT_HTTP_BACKEND env var should be set either by the rc file, or as
    # a SetEnv in the apache config somewhere
}

log_it();

$repo = "'$REPO_BASE/$repo.git'";
exec("git", "shell", "-c", "$verb $repo") unless $verb eq 'git-init';
```

Note the `$repo = "'$REPO_BASE/$repo.git'"` line: it does contains single quotes.

Comment: Thanks for the info, but shouldn't git-shell as forced-command allow a "clone" operation?

Comment: @FRank: yes, but I suppose there is an issue in the way you are calling `git-shell` (btw, did you try "`git shell`" instead of "`git-shell`"?)

Comment: Yes I did try "git shell ...", to no avail, though.

Comment: Ah, I figured it out - the command has to be in single quotes. I suppose $SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND was getting expanded before git-shell was started...

Comment: @Frank: excellent. I have included your solution in my answer, pointing out the single quotes in the gitolite forced-command script as well.

Answer (score 2):

I've made a solution using LDAP, OpenSSH (>4.9) and git-shell.

OpenSSH's ForceCommand is perfect for the job. Consider the following configuration (everyone except admins have to use git-shell):

```
Match group *,!admin    
    ForceCommand /usr/bin/git-shell -c "$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND"
```

Access control is defined using ACL-s and reponame access groups.

```
setfacl -bR -m default:group:$REPONAME:rwX -m group:$REPONAME:rwX $GITROOT/$REPONAME
setfacl -R -m default:group:$REPONAME-ro:r-X -m group:$REPONAME-ro:r-X $GITROOT/$REPONAME
```

Don't forget to run "nscd -i group", after each change.

Andor

Answer (score 2):

This authorized_keys works for me and is properly shell quoted:

```
restrict,command="/usr/bin/git-shell -c \"$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND\"" ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAA...
```

`man sshd` describes the authorized_keys file format:

> A quote may be included in the command by quoting it with a backslash.

The same man page describes `restrict`:

> Enable all restrictions, i.e. disable port, agent and X11 forwarding, as well as disabling PTY allocation and execution of ~/.ssh/rc.  If any future restriction capabilities are added to authorized_keys files they will be included in this set.